# after migration, proxmox create multiple lvm disks

Tags: migration, virtual-machine, proxmox, lvm

In a `proxmox` cluster, I migrate a vm with just one lvm disk by 100G size, in live mode, after migration finish, I see there are multiple lvm disks witch **just** one of them is attached to that vm and the others are unused.

How to prevent from migrate multiple lvm disks for one vm?

is there any problem, If I `lvremove` unused lvm disks?